# How to eliminate having an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception

I have a Java program that reads from a cvs file that looks like this:

```
2000;Mall1;8
2002;Mall3;23
2003;Mall4;31
...
```

I want the program to read from the cvs file into an array and sort the array based on the third column/field.
However, whenever I print the elements of array[2] I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. I can't see why is this happening since the array's[2] size should be already fixed.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Prog3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         String csvFile = "test.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ";";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] array = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                 System.out.println(array[2]);

                 Arrays.sort(array[2]);
                 System.out.println("Sorted\n" + Arrays.toString(array[2]));

            }

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if (br != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    br.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: by making sure the element exists before trying to access it

Comment: Arrays.sort() must expect array not element and how your code is working with passing element?

Comment: Why not use java csv parser to parse, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html

Comment: @Sanjay arra[2] is an array that holds all the entries of the 3rd field

Comment: @Sambit is parser used for defining the size?

Comment: @user47 no, `array[2]` is *not* an array. The declaration in your code as posted, clearly is `String[] array…`, so `array[2]` is a `String`. The code as posted does not pass the compiler.